# Plotting coverage depth in 1kb windows?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics, genome

I would like to plot average coverage depth across my genome, with chromosomes lined in increasing order. I have calculated coverage depth per position for my genome using samtools. I would like to generate a plot (which uses 1kb windows) like Figure 7: http://www.g3journal.org/content/ggg/6/8/2421/F7.large.jpg?width=800&height=600&carousel=1

Example dataframe:

```
Chr   locus depth
chr1    1   20  
chr1    2   24  
chr1    3   26  
chr2    1   53  
chr2    2   71  
chr2    3   74  
chr3    1   29  
chr3    2   36  
chr3    3   39
```

Do I need to change the format of the dataframe to allow continuous numbering for the V2 variable? Is there a way to average every 1000 lines, and to plot the 1kb windows? And how would I go about plotting?

UPDATE EDIT:
I was able to create a new dataset as a rolling average of non overlapping 1kb windows using this post: [Genome coverage as sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721332/genome-coverage-as-sliding-window/48722905#48722905) and I did make V2 continuous ie (1:9 instead of 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)

```
library(reshape) # to rename columns
library(data.table) # to make sliding window dataframe
library(zoo) # to apply rolling function for sliding window

#genome coverage as sliding window
Xdepth.average<-setDT(Xdepth)[, .(
  window.start = rollapply(locus, width=1000, by=1000, FUN=min, align="left", partial=TRUE),
  window.end = rollapply(locus, width=1000, by=1000, FUN=max, align="left", partial=TRUE),
  coverage = rollapply(coverage, width=1000, by=1000, FUN=mean, align="left", partial=TRUE)
), .(Chr)]
```

And to plot

```
library(ggplot2)
Xdepth.average.plot <- ggplot(Xdepth.average, aes(x=window.end, y=coverage, colour=Chr)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 20, size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Genomic Position (bp)", limits=c(0, 12071326), labels = scales::scientific) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Average Coverage Depth", limits=c(0, 200))
```

I didn't have any luck using `facet_grid` so I added reference lines using `geom_vline(xintercept = c()`. See the answer I posted below for extra details/codes as well as links to plots. Now I just need to work on the labeling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around more with the program, I was able to create a new dataset as a rolling average of non overlapping 1kb windows using this post: [Genome coverage as sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721332/genome-coverage-as-sliding-window/48722905#48722905) which did not take long or suck up a lot of memory.

```
library(reshape) # to rename columns
library(data.table) # to make sliding window dataframe
library(zoo) # to apply rolling function for sliding window
library(ggplot2)

 #upload data to dataframe, rename headers, make locus continuous, create subsets
depth <- read.table("sorted.depth", sep="\t", header=F)
depth<-rename(depth,c(V1="Chr", V2="locus", V3="coverageX", V3="coverageY")
depth$locus <- 1:12157105
Xdepth<-subset(depth, select = c("Chr", "locus","coverageX"))

#genome coverage as sliding window
Xdepth.average<-setDT(Xdepth)[, .(
  window.start = rollapply(locus, width=1000, by=1000, FUN=min, align="left", partial=TRUE),
  window.end = rollapply(locus, width=1000, by=1000, FUN=max, align="left", partial=TRUE),
  coverage = rollapply(coverage, width=1000, by=1000, FUN=mean, align="left", partial=TRUE)
), .(Chr)]
```

To plot new dataset:

```
#plot sliding window by end position and coverage
Xdepth.average.plot <- ggplot(Xdepth.average, aes(x=window.end, y=coverage, colour=Chr)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 20, size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Genomic Position (bp)", limits=c(0, 12071326), labels = scales::scientific) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Average Coverage Depth", limits=c(0, 250))
```

Then I tried to add `facet_grid(. ~ Chr)` to split by chromosome, but each panel is spaced far apart and repeats the full axis instead of it being continuous.

Update: I've tried various tweaks with `scales = "free_x"` and `space = "free_x"`. The closest was removing the limits from `scale_x_continuous()` and using both `scales = "free_x"` and `space = "free_x"` with `facet_grid` but the panel width still isn't proportional to the chromosome size and the x-axis is very wonky. For comparison, I manually added reference lines using `geom_vline(xintercept = c()` between the chromosomes (expected result).

Ideal separation and X axis without panel labels using

```
Xdepth.average.plot +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(230218, 1043402, 1360022, 2891955, 3468829, 3738990, 4829930, 5392573, 5832461, 6578212, 7245028, 8323205, 9247636, 10031969, 11123260, 12071326, 12157105))
```

[Plot with Reference lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9KoI.png)

Removing limit from `scale_x_continuous()` and using `facet_grid`

```
Xdepth.average.plot5 <- ggplot(Xdepth.average, aes(x=window.end, y=coverage, colour=Chr)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 20, size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Genomic Position (bp)", labels = scales::scientific, breaks = 
                       c(0, 2000000, 4000000, 6000000, 8000000, 10000000, 12000000)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Average Coverage Depth", limits=c(0, 200), breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
X.p5 <- Xdepth.average.plot5 + facet_grid(. ~ Chr, labeller=chr_labeller, space="free_x", scales = "free_x")+
  theme(panel.spacing.x = grid::unit(0, "cm"))
X.p5
```

[Plot with Facets and no limit on X-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8wwn.png)

Comment: You could play around with `scales = "free_x"` and `space = "free_x"` arguments in the `facet_grid(. ~ Chr)` call. You can get rid of x padding between panels by adding `expand = c(0,0)` in your `scale_x_continuous()` call to get rid of padding inside the plotting panel and use `+ theme(panel.spacing.x = grid::unit(0, "cm"))` to get rid of the padding in between panels.

Comment: @teunbrand yes , I have already tried playing around with `scales = "free_x"` and `space = "free_x"` but to no avail. Is it possible that another package is preventing it from working? The spacing between panel options worked perfectly.

Comment: I've included an example in my previous answer how I would go about plotting a genome wide coverage track.  It would need some work with the labelling of the x axis, the major grid in the theme and such, but I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: Those plots look quite good. In both cases, you could try `expand = c(0,0)` inside `scale_x_continuous` to get rid of some of the padding; ggplot adds 10% extra space by default I think.

Comment: Sorry another observation occurred to me. If you use the facets, the x-axis will try to calculate breaks and labels for the x-axis per panel, I'm afraid I forget to mention this. Furthermore, am I correct that the order of the chromosomes in your linear plot versus facetted plot is different?

Comment: They should be in order from chr1 to chr16 but looking at the plots, the facet plot looks out of order( chr1, chr10, chr 11,12, 13,14,15,16, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, even though the labels say otherwise...

Comment: Thank you so much @teunbrand. Fixed the ordering with `factor(dataset$chr, levels=c())` now `facet_grid` with `scales = "free_x"` and `space = "free_x"` is working perfectly. `expand = c(0,0)` inside `scale_x_continuous` resolved all of the x-axis issues except now my 0.0e6 scale position label is gone, gaahhhh

Comment: Well the fix for that will be to set `limits = c(0,NA)` for the `scale_x_continuous()`, but beware that acrocentric chromosomes that do not start at 0 might get a wierd look. Glad that your plots are coming along!

Answer (score 1):

To adress the plotting part of the question, have you tried adding `+ facet_grid(~ Chr)` to your plot? (or `+ facet_grid(~ V2)` depending on your variable names)

I don't see your error message if I use your example data. The message is often seen when you try to take the `log(0)`, so you may want to add a pseudocount `log(x + 1)`, take the `sqrt` or `asinh` transformation (the latter if you use negative values). On the topic of example data, it is good etiquette to post example data in a format that can be copy-pasted by other users to test your problem, e.g.:

```
depth <- data.frame(
  Chr = paste0("chr", c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)),
  locus = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  depth = c(20, 24, 26, 53, 71, 74, 29, 36, 39)
)
```

To adress the bioinformatics part, you probably want to have a look at the `GenomicRanges` bioconductor package: it has a `tileGenome()` function to make bins, and you can use `findOverlaps()` with your data and the bins. Once you have these overlaps, you can `split()` your data based on what bin it overlaps, and calculate the average coverage for each split.

Be aware that you might have to spend some time to familiarise yourself with the `GRanges` object structure and get your data in that (or `GPos`) format. `GRanges` objects resemble bed files with genomic intervals, while `GPos` objects resemble exact, single nucleotide coordinates.

However, are you sure you don't want the read count per bin, instead of the average coverage? It is good to keep in mind that coverage is a bit biased against long reads.

As a non-R solution, you could also use `bamCoverage` in the `deeptools` suite with a binsize of say, 1000 bp.

EDIT: reproducible example for plotting

```r
library(ggplot2, verbose = F, quietly = T)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(GenomicRanges))

# Setting up some dummy data
seqinfo <- rtracklayer::SeqinfoForUCSCGenome("hg19")
seqinfo <- keepStandardChromosomes(seqinfo)
granges <- tileGenome(seqinfo, tilewidth = 1e6, cut.last.tile.in.chrom = T)
granges$y <- rnorm(length(granges))

# Convert to dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(granges)

# The plotting
ggplot(df, aes(x = (start + end)/2, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ seqnames, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = NULL,
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I created a smaller test dataset and altered the `scale_y_continuous` to `scale_y_continuous( limits=c(0, 250))` and no longer got the error. `facet_grid` appeared to work find for creating individual panels but I would like the x-axis to remain continuous across all the chromosomes ie (0, 12mbp) like in the figure linked above. I will post my code as an answer for the 1kb window averages.

Comment: I manually added reference lines using `geom_vline(xintercept = c()` between the chromosomes (expected result) to use as a reference. I've tried various tweaks with `scales = "free_x"` and `space = "free_x"`. The closest was removing the limits from `scale_x_continuous()` and using both `scales = "free_x"` and `space = "free_x"` with `facet_grid` but the panel width still isn't proportional to the chromosome size and the x-axis is very wonky. I will try to update my answer to include the plots. I feel that I may run into the same issues even if i use `GRanges` because the dataset is sound(?)

Comment: Seeing a plot might help diagnose the issue. If all else fails, mapping genomic coordinates to linear coordinates might be a last resort, but let's hope it doesn't come to that.

Comment: I updated my answer below with links to the plots @teunbrand